# HTML形式のテキストからテキストのみの文字位置とそれに付随するタグをpythonで抽出したい。

Tags: python

HTML形式のテキストからテキストのみの文字位置とそれに付随するタグをpythonで抽出したいです。
文字位置はHTMLタグを抜いた文字数での抽出がしたいです。

例

```
<a>テキスト1</a><h1>テキスト2</h1><h2>テキスト3<a>テキスト4</a></h2>
```

取得したい値

```
[{'tag':a,'text':テキスト1,'start_index':0,end_index:4},{'tag':h1,'text':テキスト2,'start_index':5,end_index:9},{'tag':h2,'text':テキスト3テキスト4,'start_index':10,end_index:19},{'tag':a,'text':テキスト4,'start_index':15,end_index:19}]
```

上記のように抽出する方法はないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

テキストの重複に対応してみました。

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def extract_html_text_with_index(html):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

  result, start, end, cur, tstart, prev_len = [], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
  for i in soup.findAll():
    if start <= i.sourcepos < end:
      tstart += i.sourcepos - start - prev_len
      prev_len = len(i.name) + 3 # 3 == len('</>')
    else:
      if soup.index(i) == 0:
        cur = len(i.text) - 1
      else:
        tstart, cur = cur + 1, cur + len(i.text)
      end, prev_len = i.sourcepos + len(str(i)) - 1, 0
    start = i.sourcepos + len(i.name) + 2 # 2 == len('<>')

    result.append({
      'tag': i.name, 'text': i.text,
      'start_index': tstart, 'end_index': tstart+len(i.text)-1
    })

  return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
  from pprint import pprint

  html = [
    (
      '<a>テキスト1</a>' +
      '<h1>テキスト2</h1>' +
      '<h2>テキスト1<a>テキスト2</a></h2>'
    ),
    (
      '<h2>テキスト1<a>テキスト1</a>テキスト1<a>テキスト1</a></h2>'
    ),
    (
      '<a>テキスト1</a>' +
      '<h1>テキスト2</h1>' +
      '<h2><div>テキスト3</div>テキスト4<span>テキスト5</span></h2>' +
      '<h3>テキスト4<p>テキスト3</p></h3>' +
      '<h4>テキスト2</h4>'
    ),
  ]

  for h in html:
    result = extract_html_text_with_index(h)
    pprint(result, sort_dicts=False)

# 実行結果
[{'tag': 'a', 'text': 'テキスト1', 'start_index': 0, 'end_index': 4},
 {'tag': 'h1', 'text': 'テキスト2', 'start_index': 5, 'end_index': 9},
 {'tag': 'h2', 'text': 'テキスト1テキスト2', 'start_index': 10, 'end_index': 19},
 {'tag': 'a', 'text': 'テキスト2', 'start_index': 15, 'end_index': 19}]

[{'tag': 'h2',
  'text': 'テキスト1テキスト1テキスト1テキスト1',
  'start_index': 0,
  'end_index': 19},
 {'tag': 'a', 'text': 'テキスト1', 'start_index': 5, 'end_index': 9},
 {'tag': 'a', 'text': 'テキスト1', 'start_index': 15, 'end_index': 19}]

[{'tag': 'a', 'text': 'テキスト1', 'start_index': 0, 'end_index': 4},
 {'tag': 'h1', 'text': 'テキスト2', 'start_index': 5, 'end_index': 9},
 {'tag': 'h2', 'text': 'テキスト3テキスト4テキスト5', 'start_index': 10, 'end_index': 24},
 {'tag': 'div', 'text': 'テキスト3', 'start_index': 10, 'end_index': 14},
 {'tag': 'span', 'text': 'テキスト5', 'start_index': 20, 'end_index': 24},
 {'tag': 'h3', 'text': 'テキスト4テキスト3', 'start_index': 25, 'end_index': 34},
 {'tag': 'p', 'text': 'テキスト3', 'start_index': 30, 'end_index': 34},
 {'tag': 'h4', 'text': 'テキスト2', 'start_index': 35, 'end_index': 39}]
```

Comment: すみません。重複のことを失念していました。重複も含まれる場合は方法はありますか？

Comment: はい、了解です。少し考えてみます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Comment: 重複対応ありがとうございます！